# Can't disable keyboard with rundll32 library

Tags: c#, rundll32

Good afternoon everyone! I have a question:
I cannot disable the keyboard in C #, the error "keyboard" module is not found.
This is code how I tried to disable keyboard:

```
Process.Start("rundll32", "keyboard, disable");
```

Here's what I tried to solve this problem:
1.Used the "Autoruns" utility according to the instructions
2. With the help of the anti-virus "Dr.Web" I made a complete scan of my computer for viruses.
3.In cmd, I did a full check of files for corruption using sfc / scannow.

There is another method to remove this error using the task scheduler, but this method only removes the error window, and the error itself remains.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but maybe will work for you. Please pass the inputs like this.

```
Process.Start("rundll32.exe", "C:\Windows\system32\location\of\keyboard.dll, disable")
```